# Representing a graph with a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, graph, dijkstra

I have a question where I represent a graph in terms of a 2D array.
I have a sample as well, but I have no idea, how it works....
This is the graph I am given
[image]

And this is how they represent it using a 2D array
[image]

How does one translate to the other?

Also, this is a part of an implementation of Dijsktra's algorithm.
Here is the code for your reference, it is taken from
[geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/)

```
// A Java program for Dijkstra's single source shortest path algorithm.
// The program is for adjacency matrix representation of the graph
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class ShortestPath {
    // A utility function to find the vertex with minimum distance value,
    // from the set of vertices not yet included in shortest path tree
    static final int V = 9;
    int minDistance(int dist[], Boolean sptSet[])
    {
        // Initialize min value
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, min_index = -1;

        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
            if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min) {
                min = dist[v];
                min_index = v;
            }

        return min_index;
    }

    // A utility function to print the constructed distance array
    void printSolution(int dist[])
    {
        System.out.println("Vertex \t\t Distance from Source");
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
            System.out.println(i + " \t\t " + dist[i]);
    }

    // Function that implements Dijkstra's single source shortest path
    // algorithm for a graph represented using adjacency matrix
    // representation
    void dijkstra(int graph[][], int src)
    {
        int dist[] = new int[V]; // The output array. dist[i] will hold
        // the shortest distance from src to i

        // sptSet[i] will true if vertex i is included in shortest
        // path tree or shortest distance from src to i is finalized
        Boolean sptSet[] = new Boolean[V];

        // Initialize all distances as INFINITE and stpSet[] as false
        for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
            dist[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            sptSet[i] = false;
        }

        // Distance of source vertex from itself is always 0
        dist[src] = 0;

        // Find shortest path for all vertices
        for (int count = 0; count < V - 1; count++) {
            // Pick the minimum distance vertex from the set of vertices
            // not yet processed. u is always equal to src in first
            // iteration.
            int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet);

            // Mark the picked vertex as processed
            sptSet[u] = true;

            // Update dist value of the adjacent vertices of the
            // picked vertex.
            for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)

                // Update dist[v] only if is not in sptSet, there is an
                // edge from u to v, and total weight of path from src to
                // v through u is smaller than current value of dist[v]
                if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] != 0 && dist[u] != Integer.MAX_VALUE && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v])
                    dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
        }

        // print the constructed distance array
        printSolution(dist);
    }

    // Driver method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /* Let us create the example graph discussed above */
        int graph[][] = new int[][] { { 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0 },
                                    { 4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0 },
                                    { 0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2 },
                                    { 0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0 },
                                    { 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0 },
                                    { 0, 0, 4, 14, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0 },
                                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6 },
                                    { 8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7 },
                                    { 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0 } };
        ShortestPath t = new ShortestPath();
        t.dijkstra(graph, 0);
    }
}
```

If this is the graph given to me, for example, how would I represent it using a 2D array?
[image]

Comment: @AKSingh Thanks for noticing! I've edited it now. I did google it, but I couldn't find any resources which explains this properly. If you have any links which do, please send them here :) Thanks again!

Comment: Here is one link on graph representations. If this does not help you, do comment. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/

Comment: @AKSingh Thank you! Also, I don't think the 2D array they've given as an input here is an adjacency matrix. They actually contain the weights don't they

Comment: For instance, consider the graph {{0,1,1,0},{0,0,01},{1,1,0,0},{1,1,1,0}}. How would this be represented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out!

In the example graph, there are 9 vertices. Therefore a 9x9 2D matrix is created, such that:

- Row 1 corresponds to vertex 0, Row 2 corresponds to vertex 1 and so on

and

- Column 1 corresponds to vertex 0, Column 2 corresponds to vertex 1 and so on

and the array is filled such that it contains the weight of the edges between node x and y. For example: Row 1 column 2 (map[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdI7Q.png)) contains the weight of the edge between vertex 0 and vertex 1.

Therefore for a graph with n vertices, an nxn array needs to be created such that the location[x][y] in the array contains the weight between edge from x to y.

As for the example graph I had asked the solution for, this would be its corresponding 2D Matrix:
It is a little big, because we create a 16x16 2D matrix
[image]

Comment: Can you now create matrix for the next graph that you have mentioned in the question?

Comment: @AKSingh It took me a while but i finally managed to create a solution for the graph imentioned!

Comment: @AKSingh Thank you for all your help! It's greatly appreciated! I hope you have a nice day :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `1000` in `[1][2]` and `[2][1]`?You are welcome :)

Comment: @AKSingh oops, yeah... I'll correct it :))

Answer (score 2):

You can read it like a coordinate table.
Every row represents a single vertex and every column value on the same row represents the distance to the Nth vertex.

**Examples:**

**0, 1:** first row, second column has the value of 4; which means vertex 0's distance to vertex 1 is 4.

**1, 7:** second row, 8th column has the value of 11; which means vertex 1's distance to vertex 7 is 11.

And so on...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They have used an `adjacency matrix` to represent an *weighted undirected graphs*. According to *geeksforgeeks*:

```
Adjacency Matrix: Adjacency Matrix is a 2D array of size V x V where V is the 
number of vertices in a graph. Let the 2D array be adj[][], a slot adj[i][j] = 1 
indicates that there is an edge from vertex i to vertex j. Adjacency matrix for 
undirected graph is always symmetric. Adjacency Matrix is also used to represent 
weighted graphs. If adj[i][j] = w, then there is an edge from vertex i to vertex 
j with weight w.
```

As the last two line state, *adjacency matrix can be used to store a weighted graph which they have done in this case*.

There might be few problems if you use adjacency matrix to represent weighted graphs. Here we use `0` to *represent no-edge between any two vertices*. *If there is any graph which has a weight `0`in the graph, then a little change in the adjacency matrix will be needed since `0` already represents no-edge*.

---

In the comments you mention about another graph. That one, however, is ***not** weighted*. *It is also **not** undirected graph since its not symmetric*.

---

Do comment if you have any other doubts.

Comment: Thank you so much!  if the graph is weighted, however, I will edit the question to mention the graph, How would it be represented?